# ls- ltr is failed in remote sftp, if folder is having more than 38 files(objects)

Tags: docker, kubernetes, sftp, kubernetes-pod, alpine-linux

When I access my sftp remote site from a kubernetes pod, I have a strange question,

```
sftp user@<host>

/cb/folder1/abc
/cb/folder/xyz
```

I can see all the files in the folder below, `/cb/folder1/abc`, when I run "ls -ltr," however the number of files is less than 38.

Following folder is `/cb/folder/xyz` the `ls -ltr` command hangs, and nothing appears for several minutes. The number of files is 40 (>38 files).

However, the `ls -ltr` command works just well when I delete files one at a time and when the number of files is equal to or less than 38.

In addition, rather than stressing over the number of files, if I try to connect to sftp with my localhost using filezilla, it works.

In light of this, the problem only arises when I access a sftp location from a kuberntes pod.

Could somebody advice on how to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I highly doubt Kubernetes has anything to do with it. Can you recreate the issue from just an instance of the `alpine` container?

Comment: @Botje let me check it

Comment: @Botje checked locally using Alpine-Linux version but no issues, can list files more than 38.

Comment: @Botje figured it this is happening on all the pods in EKS worker nodes, if I manually login to worker and try sftp, same issue exists. Therefore this is on EKS node level.